# $T$ is injective if and only if $ST=I_V$ for some $S\in\mathcal{L}(W,V)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, solution-verification

Is the following argument correct?

> Suppose $W$ is finite-dimensional and $T\in\mathcal{L}(V,W)$. Prove
> that $T$ is injective if and only if there exists
> $S\in\mathcal{L}(W,V)$ such that $ST$ is the indentity map on $V$.

*Proof.* $(\Rightarrow)$. Assume that $T\in\mathcal{L}(V,W)$ is injective, from theorem $\textbf{2.34}$ there exists a subspace $U$ such that $W = \{Tv:v\in V\}\oplus U$. Now define the map $S$ such that $S(Tv+u)=v$.

Prior to continuing with the above argument we show that the above mapping is well defined. Assume that $S(Tv+u)=w_1$ and $S(Tv+u)=w_2$, then by definition of $S$ we have $Tv=w_1$ and $Tv=w_2$ then given the injectivity of $T$ we have $w_1=w_2$.

To prove linearity observe that $$S(c_1(Tv_1+u_1)+c_2(Tv_2+u_2)) = S(T(c_1v_1+c_2v_2)+c_1u_1+c_2u_2)$$
$$ = c_1v_1+c_2v_2$$
and
$$S(c_1(Tv_1+u_1))+S(c_2(Tv_2+u_2)) = S(T(c_1v_1)+c_1u_1)+S(T(c_2v_2)+c_2u_2) $$
$$ = c_1v_1+c_2v_2$$

Thus $S\in\mathcal{L}(W,V)$ and given the definition of $S$ it is evident that $ST=I_V$.

$(\Leftarrow)$. Conversely assume that there exists a map $S\in\mathcal{L}(W,V)$ such that $ST=I_V$. Let $v\in V$ and assume that $v\in\operatorname{null}T$ that is $Tv=0$ then $STv=S(0) = 0 = v =I_Vv$ consequently $\operatorname{null}T = \{0\}$ then by theorem $\textbf{3.16}$ it follows that $T$ is injective.

$\blacksquare$

**Note:**

- $\textbf{2.34}$ - Given a finite dimensional vector space $V$ and a subspace $W$ of $V$ there exists a susbspace $U$ of $V$ such that $V = W\oplus U$.
- $\textbf{3.16}$ - A Linear map $T\in\mathcal{L}(V,W)$ is injective if and only if $\operatorname{null}T = \{0\}$.

Comment: @Bernard Sorry let me correct it

Comment: Your justification for the good definition of $S$ does not make sense. You are assuming $w_1=S(Tv+u)=w_2$ to deduce $w_1=w_2$, which is tautological. To justify the good definition of $S$, you should check that the writing of any vector of $W$ in the form $Tv+u$ is unique. What you already know is that a writing in the form $z+u$ with $z\in \operatorname{Im}(T)\oplus U$ is unique, so you only need to check that any element of $\operatorname{Im}(T)$ is uniquely written as $Tv$. But this is exactly injectivity of $T$, so everything works well.

Comment: Typo: I meant "with $z\in \operatorname{Im}(T)$ and $u\in U$".

Comment: @Suzet So What you are saying is that I start with the assumption that $Tv_1+u_1 = Tv_2+u_2$ then given that $W =\operatorname{range}T\oplus U$ it follows that $Tv_1=Tv_2$ then given injectivity of $T$ it follows that $v_1=v_2$ and thus $S(Tv_1+u_1) = S(Tv_2+u_2)$?

Comment: @Suzet and apart from the error that you pointed out is the rest of the argument correct?

Comment: Exactly, you perfectly nailed it down. Aside from this remark, everything is correct (and well redacted) in your proof.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80500/discussion-between-atif-farooq-and-suzet).